# jQuery synchronous animation trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing a game in jQuery and I'm a little stuck.
I would like to trigger in the draw phase a sequence of webkit animations synchronously, with 1 second delay in between. I attach the relevant code (which is not working properly).:

jQuery:

```js
var colour_sequence = [];
var drawGame = function() {
  for (var index = 0; index < colour_sequence.length; index++) {
    $(queue_selector).queue("syncFnQueue", runMe(toggle_tile, colour_sequence[index], queue_selector));
  }
  var current_tile = chooseRandomTileId();
  $(queue_selector).queue("syncFnQueue", runMe(toggle_tile, current_tile, queue_selector));
  $(queue_selector).dequeue("syncFnQueue");

  colour_sequence.push(current_tile);
}


var toggle_tile = function(element) {
  $(element).toggleClass(animated_img_class);
  $(element).toggleClass(simple_img_class);
};

var runMe = function(fn, e, selec) {
  return function() {
    fn(e);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(selec).dequeue("syncFnQueue");
    }, 1000);
  };
};
```

CSS:

```css
.game-img {
  opacity: 1;
}
.game-img-animated {
  -webkit-animation: grow-shrink 1s ease-in-out;
  animation: grow-shrink 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<img id="red-brain" class="img-responsive game-img" src="images/brain_red.png" alt="" />
<img id="yellow-brain" class="img-responsive game-img" src="images/brain_yellow.png" alt="" />
<img id="green-brain" class="img-responsive game-img" src="images/brain_green.png" alt="" />
<img id="blue-brain" class="img-responsive game-img" src="images/brain_blue.png" alt="" />
```

EDIT: Sorry for the ambiguity of the previous question. The problem is that the code above seems to trigger the animations rather randomly. Sometimes they trigger correctly sometimes not at all.

EDIT 2: SOLVED. Will update with solution in a few days.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle of this please, clearly demonstrating the problem? Thanks.

Comment: To create a jsFiddle I should include more code. Since the program is for a contest, I can't do that right now. I solved my problem with incremental timeout events, and I will post the code in my github repo when the contest is over for anyone who's interested. I will include a link in the original post. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `animation-delay` option in CSS with relative number which you can put and take from data-attribute.

```
<img id="red-brain" class="img-responsive game-img" data-delay=".3s" src="images/brain_red.png" alt="" />

$(this).css({"animation-delay" : $(this).attr(data-delay)})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem lies rather with the synchronous aspect of my question than with the delay. I edited the original post to clarify that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like part of your problem is you are actually calling the runMe function instead of queueing it to be run:

**This will call runMe immediately**

```
$(queue_selector).queue("syncFnQueue", 
  runMe(toggle_tile, colour_sequence[index], queue_selector));
```

**This will queue a function that will call runMe later:**

```
$(queue_selector).queue("syncFnQueue",
 function(){ runMe(toggle_tile, colour_sequence[index], queue_selector)});
```

Comment: I think I took that into account because runMe is returning a function so i'm queueing the function runMe is returning, and I'm eliminating the "function inside loop" warnings. Anyway I tried it (with runMe returning and not returning a function) and it didn't work either.